# mySQL DATETIME select in between dates

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a mySQL table named events with 4 fields (event_id, event_name, event_start_date, event_end_date)

The problem is retrieving the correct events

I would get the record for all the active events in a time period for example between 2011/03/01 to 2011/03/30

1. event 1 starts at 2011/03/10 and ends 2011/03/20 (start and ends
   inside)
2. event 2 starts at 2011/02/05 and ends 2011/03/23 (starts before and
   ends inside)
3. event 3 starts at 2011/03/25 and ends 2011/05/01 (starts inside and
   ends after)
4. event 4 starts at 2011/01/25 and ends 2011/10/12 (starts before and
   ends after)

All events are active during the considered time period and should be retrieved as records

I have no idea how to make it work correctly!
Solutions? Suggestions? Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: My answer ended up as a comment which I can't delete...sigh

Comment: [This question has a similar answer which applies.][1]  Mark Buyers has given the specific answer for this question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming @Start and @End hold the date range you are looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM Events
  -- Exclude items known to be outside the range
WHERE NOT ((event_end_date < @Start) OR (event_start_date > @End))
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget, if any answer solves your question, you should click on the checkbox next to that answer to let future visitors to your question know that it was the answer that fixed your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    event_id,
    event_name,
    event_start_date,
    event_end_date
FROM events
WHERE event_start_date <= '2011-03-30'
AND event_end_date >= '2011-03-01'
```

Comment: that would only return the event 1 that starts at 2011/03/10 and ends 2011/03/20 (start and ends inside) but not the others

Comment: @GAVELLO: Why do you think that? Are you just guessing or did you try it? If you tried it, please post the exact query you tried.

Comment: //$sql = 'SELECT * FROM '. self::$table_name .' WHERE event_start_date >= "'. $start_date .'" AND event_end_date <= "'. $end_date.'"' ;

Comment: WHERE event_start_date <= '2011-03-30' AND event_end_date >= '2011-03-01' (like you wrote) returns only the event 3 and 4 but not 1 and 2

Comment: @GAVELLO: Why did you change the query? I wrote `WHERE event_start_date <= '2011-03-30' AND event_end_date >= '2011-03-01'` and you changed it to `WHERE event_start_date >= '2011-03-01' AND event_end_date <= '2011-03-30'`. Obviously if you write something completely different without understanding what you are doing then it's not going to work, is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From temp where mydate >= '2011-03-10' and mydate =< '2011-03-20';
```

and so on

Comment: Not so easy this would return only the events tat starts and ends inside the time period.